# How to limit the display of items and convert him to number

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

1) via `element=driver_find_elements_by_xpath("any value")`
and command

```
for elements in element:
print(elements)
```

I get a list of 50 values I need (`elements`)
how do i limit the list which i get to 10 or 20 values?

2) How does the list received by the command `print()` convert all values obtained from string to number?

Comment: Can you explain more with sample input output?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/gmvK3QNCL97O52 in the console, I get a list. It must be reduced from 50 to 20 and converted to number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `range()` function for the `for` loop and you can limit the printing values to certain number. Try the below code:

Suppose you have some values in the below list

```
elements = driver_find_elements_by_xpath("any value")
```

then you can do like below :

```
for i in range(20):
    print(element[i])
```

make sure that, where `20 <= len(elements)` condition is satisfied.

If you want to convert a `string` to an `int` then you can do like below:

```
for i in range(20):
    print(int(elements[i]))
```

To know more about the python `for` loop, refer [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)

I hope it helps...

Comment: it works, I changed a little for myself. which time you helped me. thank